# how to install gdb on MacBook Air m2

Tags: segmentation-fault, gdb

I am getting segmentation fault error in C code so I think the best thing to use to find error would be gdb but gdb is not found.

Answer (score 2):

GDB has not (yet) been ported to MacOS running on the M2 (AArch64) architecture.  Even GDB for MacOS on the old x86-64 was not very well tested as far as I know.

I believe lldb might be available for the MacOS/M2 target, but I know nothing about installing this debugger on MacOS.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use gdb on mac, which is as Andrew stated, not well tested, you can use x86_64 version of brew:

First, you need to install x86_64 brew:

```
arch -x86_64 /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

Then, you can install gdb right away using:

```
arch -x86_64 zsh
arch -x86_64 brew install gdb
```

In addition, you might want need to alias x86_64 brew by adding it to your .zshrc

```
alias x86brew='arch -x86_64 /usr/local/bin/brew'
```

So you can just use "x86brew" to install without having to "arch -x86_64 zsh"

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully resolved it in mac m2 where i had brew installed already

I followed the above post but got minor issues which i got resolved

```
arch -x86_64 /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

Then i used this

```
arch -x86_64 zsh
arch -x86_64 brew install gdb # it triggered the following warnings
```

Error: Cannot install under Rosetta 2 in ARM default prefix (/opt/homebrew)!
To rerun under ARM use:
arch -arm64 brew install ...
To install under x86_64, install Homebrew into /usr/local.

Then I resolved this way

```
sudo rm -rf /opt/homebrew
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```